# Display theme layouts

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I have done a lot of searching and have not really found an answer for this yet. I have created a theme that has extensive customizer options. For my `index.php` page I have various layouts that a user can choose from. Grid, list, etc.

I have seen theme demo sites use layout links like `mysite.com/?home_layout=grid` for example. How is this accomplished?

Looking for any information on this matter. Links, tutorials, other questions. Anything that could help me.

Greatly appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've used multisite to do something similar (display multiple themes). https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: While I do understand this concept, I would think that creating a network of sites is a bit of an overkill to simply display various page layouts. This is a single theme with multiple layouts that a user can select through the customizer. I appreciate the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you have implemented this feature, but I'll explain how I managed to do this for my own theme.

Let's say you have developed a theme option page for your theme, and you get the layout's value this way:

```
psyrix_get_theme_option( 'layout' );
```

And the returned value is a string, for example 'grid'. There should be a function that chooses the proper template part to fetch for your front-end. You can use a filter inside that function:

```
function choose_template_for_my_blog( ){
    $layout = psyrix_get_theme_option( 'layout' );
    $layout = apply_filters('psyrix_filter_layout', $excerpt);
}
```

Now, you can create a simple plugin and filter the layout based on URL queries:

```
add_filter('psyrix_filter_layout','filter_demo_layouts',11,1);
function filter_demo_layouts( ){
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['home_layout'] ) ){
        return $_REQUEST['home_layout'];
    }
}
```

This way, when you try and access `mysite.com/?home_layout=grid`, the `grid` value will be passed to your `choose_template_for_my_blog()` function, which will override the layout.

This is a basic and simple example of how to use this. You should add more filters and sanitize the user's input before pushing this to published state.

Comment: I have implemented this feature using Wordpress' built-in customizer. If my option field looks like [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gAQuMcJC) then I assume I would just need to tweak what you have done above to pull out the value of "layout" and make the value available to be passed in the url?

Comment: Yes. It was just a simple example about how to implement filters to achieve this. You can simply add a `switch` and check URL's value.